# Sync SQLite Database to google drive without confirmation

Tags: android, upload, google-drive-api

I have to implement synchronization  in my android app. So, I need to use user's google drive to store and retrieve info. I have created functionality to store *.db file to drive. But problem is user has to confirm file upload operation every time. I want to upload file on every app close without confirmation. Is it possible ? Is there other way to synchronize sqlite db without having own server ?

```
public static void backUpDb(final Activity context){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

            Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
            saveFileToDrive( context);
        }
    })
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
            new OnConnectionFailedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(
                        ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "GoogleApiClient connection failed: "
                                    + result.toString());
                    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                        // show the localized error
                        // dialog.
                        GooglePlayServicesUtil
                                .getErrorDialog(
                                        result.getErrorCode(),
                                        context, 0).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        result.startResolutionForResult(
                                context,
                                REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG,
                                "Exception while starting resolution activity",
                                e);
                    }

                }
            }).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    //mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();        
}



public static void saveFileToDrive(final Activity context) {
    Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                        return;
                    }
                    OutputStream outputStream = result.getContents()
                            .getOutputStream();
                    try {
                        // outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());

                        //ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName);
                        //dbFile.
                        int size = (int) dbFile.length();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
                        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dbFile));
                        buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        buf.close();

                        byte[] b = "aa".getBytes();
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                    }

                    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType("db");
                    MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setMimeType(mimeType).setTitle("aldkan.db")
                            .build();
                    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                            .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                            .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                            .setInitialContents(result.getContents())
                            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                    try {
                        context.startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, 2,
                                null, 0, 0, 0);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CreateFileActivity is available as a convenient way to build a file upload UI for Google Drive. However, you can instead just use the API directly to create and modify files, as explained in the [Creating Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#creating_files_programmatically) guide, to avoid any user interaction.